# Time axis manipulation

Tags: python, time, axis

I have the following time vector in seconds:

`time = [0,1,2,4,5,7,0,1,2,4,6,7,8,0,1,2,3]`

`def get_elapsed_time(time):`

```
for i in range(0,len(time)-1):

    if time[i+1] > time[i]:
        elapsed_time.append(time[i])
    else:
        tr = time[i]
        t1 = tr + 1e-3 # add 1 millisecond to keep both values..
        elapsed_time.append(tr)
        elapsed_time.append(t1)
        while time[i+1] > time[i]:
              t2 = time[i] + tr
              elapsed_time.append(t2)
```

`elapsed_time = []`

`get_elapsed_time(time)`

I am trying to create a function (above) that will condition the time axis to sum the values when the counter resets to zero. i.e. the time vector output I am trying to achieve is:

`elapsed_time = [0,1,2,4,5,7,7.001,8.001,9.001,11.001,13.001,14.001,15.001,15.002,16.002,17.002,18,002]`

This seems like a relatively simple task using a loop to recondition time vectors of this type, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. My code is giving me the wrong values as below:

`elapsed time = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7.001, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8.001, 0, 1, 2]`

Any HELP on this would be greatly appreciated...!! Thanks.

Jordan.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic you want to implement. And are the last two elements in elapsed_time a typo ("18" and "002", separated by comma)? Which coding language do you use? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Hi Lars. Sorry yes the last two are a typo. 18,002 should read: 18.002 I am using Python language...

Comment: I basically want a rolling summation of the time axis...The zeros in the original time vector are when the clock has reset but the values in reality are not zero. They need to be added on to the last value before the clock reset...hope that makes sense...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, it is not neccessary to add the millisecond, and your while loop does not do anything. I think you should change your approach and just keep track of the times when an upcoming reset is detected:

```
def get_elapsed_time(time):
    elapsed_time = []
    last_time_before_reset = 0
    for i in range(0,len(time)-1):
        current_time = last_time_before_reset + time[i]
        elapsed_time.append(current_time)
        if time[i+1] <= time[i]:
            # upcoming time reset
            last_time_before_reset = current_time
    return elapsed_time
```

Comment: Quick question - If some of the resets (not all) were to 0.1 instead of 0.0 how would one handle this?

Comment: The code should be able to handle this, as long as time[i+1] is not greater than time[i]. But in that case you would have to find another way to detect resets anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There should be good `pandas` solutions, but here is a simple Python loop.

```
time = [0,1,2,4,5,7,0,1,2,4,6,7,8,0,1,2,3]
#multiply by 1000 to avoid float math problems and work just with integers
time = [1000 * i for i in time]
newtime = time[:1]
#counter to keep track of resets
s = 0
for i, t in enumerate(time[1:]):
    #adjust counter
    if t == 0:
        s += time[i] + 1
    #append list
    newtime.append(t + s)
#reverse multiplication by 1000
newtime = [i / 1000 for i in newtime]
print(newtime)
#output
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.001, 8.001, 9.001, 11.001, 13.001, 14.001, 15.001, 15.002, 16.002, 17.002, 18.002]
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Comment: Quick question - If some of the resets (not all) were to 0.1 instead of 0.0 how would one handle this?

Comment: Substitute `if t == 0:` with `if t < 1000:`. If you don't mind float math problems and don't want to integrate the multiplication to work only with integers, it would be of course `if t < 1:`.